# Align components in Groupbox in c#

Tags: c#, alignment, groupbox

I am having a group box of width 900px and height 250px. and have to place 20 around radio buttons in it in a 4 rows * 5 columns tabular format. But at present its coming in 20 rows * 1 column format.
And i have to do this using groupbox. 
I'll be glad for the answers thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not imporssible, as Group control does not support overflow style child management. You have two options (maybe more):

1. Create your custom group box and implement the "row overflow" logic yourself;
2. You might embed a child TableLayoutPanel or ListBox in your group box, and add child items there;

for the TableLayoutPanel option, you might try below snippet to see if it matches your requriment:

```
TableLayoutPanel Table = new TableLayoutPanel();
Table.AutoSize = true;
Table.RowCount = 4;
Table.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
Table.GrowStyle = System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddCols;
this.Controls.Add(Table);
```

for the listbox, you can try this [RadioListBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18526/RadioListBox-A-ListBox-with-Radio-Buttons-Winforms), and also set:

```
 listBox1.MultiColumn = true;
```

And also you need adjust the listbox height so that exactly 4 rows are there.

If WPF is an option, this will be trivial as you can do this with XAML, and implementation your own ItemTemplate is just a breeze.